# Game matchmaking using Azure cloud

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, cloud

I am in the process of building a basic windows phone 8 game with an Azure back-end. I am looking into solutions to implement some form of matchmaking for my game through Azure. I would like to run some form of "game master" in the cloud rather than in the app so if two individuals connect to each other, I can manage the whole game flow using Azure back-end.

I have looked at Azure Mobile Services, but it would seem that it only provides databasing functionality for your app. I think Azure Cloud Service provides such functionality, but I am unclear as to how I connect to Azure Cloud Service from my Windows phone app.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a regular web service in Azure WebSites or Cloud Service (MVC / Web API) which you could then consume from your WP app:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-rest-service-aspnet-api-sql-database/
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-web-api-from-a-windows-phone-8-application